# ElasticSearch selecting specific rows from a document field

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a type containing one text file per document. There are few fields for metadata (like file size, author, etc.) and one field contains the whole content of the files

Something like:

```
{
  size: 10,
  Author: "Michael",
  content: "all the text from a possibly very big file"
}
```

I need to show in a web page the content of a selected file.

Considering that the size of each file can exceed 100,000 rows, which are my options for paging through the content of each field?